# Understanding 1,537cM match to person and 1,950cM match to their uncle

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis, half-siblings

I have a match with a female that is a few years younger than me (she is in the 60s). She and I match at 1,537 cM across 47 segments.

Her Uncle (Paternal Uncle, as far as I know) is a match with me at 1,950 cM across 76 segments.

I have never met these two individuals or ever heard anything about them.  The female's father (he is deceased) grew up in a small town with my mother (3 years different in ages).  My Mom was married at the time to my father(?).

When I ask for matches I am getting no one with my last name, but a lot of people I have never heard of.

What is your best and candid explanation of the situation?

I want to see if it matches mine.  The way I have worded the preceding, obviously gives you a clue to what I think.

Comment: Sounds like her uncle is probably also your uncle. Do you know the identities of all of your mother's siblings?

Answer (score 1):

[The Shared cM Project 3.0 tool v4 suggests for 1,537 cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1537) that the relationship has these probabilities (based on stats from [The DNA Geek](https://thednageek.com/the-limits-of-predicting-relationships-using-dna/)):

> - **100.00%** Grandparent Aunt / Uncle Half Sibling Niece / Nephew Grandchild
> - **~0%** Great-Aunt / Uncle Great-Niece / Nephew

and that the:

> [second] set of relationships is just within the threshold for 1537cM, but has a zero probability in thednageek's table of probabilities

Based on the age of your match in comparison to your own age (which is three years difference) I think your first theory should be that you may be half siblings.

[The Shared cM Project 3.0 tool v4 suggests the same relationships for 1,950 cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1950) and you already know this match is an uncle (and you think that uncle is paternal) to the first match (who may be a half sibling to you), and this shared centimorgan value would suggest that her uncle may also be your uncle.

Comment: I would like to see more explanations......for this type of surprising situation I want to be sure of what has happened......if I can not get more explanations here can someone tell me where to go to get additional accurate and candid explanations. Thank you.

Comment: I can only assess the evidence you presented in your question, which I have already done in my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that clarification....I thought others answered questions also....since I saw some questions with multiple answers.

Comment: Lots of others answer questions too, and there can be multiple answers to any question. My comments are only about my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing the 1537cM with this female It would be half sibling based on both your ages. Share the same father , different mother . You both share the same Paternal Uncle . Based on the information you have provided.

Answer (score -1):

Greg , DNA doesn’t lie - you have presented the information and the return replies reflect your situation . Perhaps for real piece of mind you make contact with the female ( half sibling ) and both do DNA samples within your GPS or pathology departments .. best of luck.

Comment: Please just edit your previous answer if you want to add more information, rather than posting it as a new answer.